# How can I get a google IdToken?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-signin

I am using this **plugin**: [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

After the user selects his `Gmail` correctly I get an object with a lot of different user informations

and on the **backend side** I use Java and followed this **tutorial:** [backend-auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Now I got the problem that I only get an Access Token via the `googleplus plugin`, but I need an IDToken. This is the code I used:

```
this.googlePlus.login({webclientId:'778525824123-83qa65tspdfd5c6i6roquf3dd41m3nk8.apps.googleusercontent.com'})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}
)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Maybe there is something wrong with my webclientId? I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by not using the npm version, I used:

ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus ......